# How to do something in MainActivity after the AsyncTask onPostExecute is done

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, google-places-api

I am trying to get the LatLngs so I can find the nearest place of the search result, I am trying it this way, but the getLatLngs returns null because it hasn't yet initialized.How do I access stuff from MainActivity after the onPostExecute is done.Thank you in advance.

```
    public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    private ArrayList<LatLng> LatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
    private LatLng latLngMain;
    private LatLng shortestLatLng;


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(s);

        shortestLatLng = DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    }

    private LatLng DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList)
    {
        int index = 0;
        LatLng shortest;
        double shortestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0;i<nearbyPlacesList.size();i++)
        {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            HashMap<String, String> googleNearbyPlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
            String nameOfPlace = googleNearbyPlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googleNearbyPlace.get("vicinity");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lng"));


            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            LatLngs.add(latLng);

            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(nameOfPlace + " : " + vicinity);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

            if(mMap!=null)
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }

        for(int i = 0;i<LatLngs.size();i++)
        {
            double deltaLat = latLngMain.latitude - LatLngs.get(i).latitude;
            double deltaLng = latLngMain.longitude - LatLngs.get(i).longitude;
            double distanceInDegree = Math.sqrt(deltaLat * deltaLat + deltaLng * deltaLng);
            double distanceInMeter = distanceInDegree * 4000;
            if(distanceInMeter<shortestDistance)
            {
                shortestDistance=distanceInMeter;
                index = i;
            }
        }

        shortest = LatLngs.get(index);

        return shortest;
    }

    public LatLng getShortestLatLng()
    {
        return shortestLatLng;
    }

}
```

In MainActivity

```
getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData).get();
nearestDistance = getNearbyPlaces.getShortestLatLng();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your LatLngs field before calling methods on it.

Replace

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> LatLngs;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> LatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your code, you initialize it only in loop of DisplayNearbyPlaces method, and if, for example, 
nearbyPlacesList is empty, then body of this loop does not run and field remains uninitialized.

Comment: I did that, but now the Arraylist is just empty, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0